# program not giving [Finished in xs] when it's done

Tags: python, selenium, sublimetext3

i am getting the **correct results** but in sublime editor it always gives [Finished in xs] when it's done

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
#chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print (driver.title)
x=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
x.clear()
x.send_keys("Hello world from python")
x.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
li=[]
links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
li=[link.get_attribute("href") for link in links if "google" not in link.get_attribute("href")]
for i in range(2,7):
    driver.get(li[i])
    print (driver.title)
driver.close()
print ("DONE")
```

This is the output:

```
Google
Hello, World! - Learn Python - Free Interactive Python Tutorial
Python Program to Print Hello world!
Say "Hello, World!" With Python | HackerRank
Hello World: Create your First Python Program
Hello World in Python || Python Tutorial || Python Programming - YouTube
DONE
```

I want to know what seems to be the problem with this code only that it is not giving [Finish in ..] in the end

Comment: Sublime adds that string "[Finished in xxxs]".  It's completely independent from your program from my understanding.  You can always use the time module to time your program if you want to calculate the execution time outside of Sublime.

Comment: Yes, the indication of the time taken is calculated and displayed by Sublime's build system (although you can turn it off by using `"quiet": true` in your `sublime-build` file.

Comment: @OdatNurd I want to show it not hide it :)

Comment: @Kyle I think it has to do with `selenium` because every other program I have gives *[Finished in ..]*

Comment: timmyturner I was just verifying what @Kyle mentioned. This is indeed being added by Sublime. If you want your own program to display that information outside of Sublime, then you need to add it manually.